# python Pandas if word in column in list add Y flag in new column

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, filter

I can't figure out if statements in python pandas.

I have a dataframe df

```
Category | Count
A           45756
B           5857
C           57876
```

I create a list and then use it as a hierarchy

```
list_s = {'A':'Y',
'B':'Y'}
df['Flag'] = df['Category'].replace(list_s)
```

but I get

```
Category | Count   | Flag 
A           45756     Y
B           5857      Y
C           57876     C
```

instead of

```
Category | Count   | Flag 
A           45756     Y
B           5857      Y
C           57876
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` with a `lambda` function in which you utilize dictionary's `get` method where you can pass a default value

```
list_s = {'A':'Y', 'B':'Y'}
df['Flag'] = df['Category'].map(lambda x: list_s.get(x, ''))

print(df)

  Category  Count Flag
0        A  45756    Y
1        B   5857    Y
2        C  57876
```

Comment: worked beautifully - thank you, do you happen to know a good documentation of lambda (beyond the python documentation?)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [8]: df['Flag'] = df['Category'].map(list_s).fillna('')

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
  Category  Count Flag
0        A  45756    Y
1        B   5857    Y
2        C  57876
```

Comment: I didn't understand completely.  OP said they got the `'C'`.  But there's no way to get that without some extra work.  So I assumed they meant that as expected output.  Either way, `fillna('')` or `fillna('C')` is super useful.

Comment: @piRSquared, i think `C` - is the result of `replace()` function

Comment: Wow!  I just woke up, I've got no excuse for missing that :-).